# PyQGIS - export map using a 2nd layer for my extents

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, extents

I wish to export an OSM as a TIFF image but use a 2nd shapefile layer (which I call 'mask') for the extents of the TIFF output.  Similar to how one uses the QGIS GUI by selecting Project / Import-Export / Export Map to Image / Calculate from Layer drop-down.  I would prefer to some type of "select by name" layer for the 2nd layer (my masking layer), as I will be running this type script for many TIFFs. The 'mask' name will remain the same but the extents will change.

So it appears I would need to change the section under export_Map (self): at #set extent, but have not understood a way to point to my mask layer through my research so far.

FYI - I structured this script as a class and I am using ScriptRunner currently to run/test my script.

```
class OSMproject:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface        
        
    def load_area(self):
        project = QgsProject.instance() 
        
    def load_masks(self):
        project = QgsProject.instance()
        mask = QgsVectorLayer('B:\\USAF\\Section_1\\Masks Quarters\\USAF_D3_maskA1.shp','USAF_A1_maskA1')
                
        project.instance().addMapLayer(mask)      
        activeLayer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        renderer = activeLayer.renderer()
        symbol = renderer.symbol()
        from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
        symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(61,105,249,255))

        canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        canvas.zoomScale(5000)
        canvas.refresh()
        
    def load_OSM(self):
        iface = self.iface
        tms = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
        layer = QgsRasterLayer(tms,'OSM', 'wms')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        
    def export_Map(self):   
        # create image
        img = QImage(QSize(8700, 6525), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        
        # create map settings
        ms = QgsMapSettings()
        
        # create painter
        p = QPainter()
        p.begin(img)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
               
        # set layers to render
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OSM')
        ms.setLayers([layer[0]])
        
        # set extent
        rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
        rect.scale(1.1)
        ms.setExtent(rect)
        
        # set ouptut size
        ms.setOutputSize(img.size())
        
        # setup qgis map renderer
        render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
        render.start()
        render.waitForFinished()
        p.end()
        
        # save the image
        img.save('B:\\Output_TEST.tif')

def run_script(iface):
        ap = OSMproject(iface)
        ap.load_area()
        ap.load_masks()
        ap.load_OSM()
        ap.export_Map()
```